# MDSpinner from kivymd doesn't work for me as expected

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

In my project , I use the `MDSpinner` class from KivyMD to show loading status of a widget. The code is as follows:

KV file( relevant part)

```
    MDSpinner:
        id: spinner
        size_hint: None, None
        size: dp(46), dp(46)
        pos_hint: { 'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .9 }
        active: True if app.processing else False
```

I have a Boolean property processing and the corresponding on_processing function as follows

```
class Mark2MarketApp(MDApp):
    processing = BooleanProperty(defaultValue=False)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        start = time.time()
        Builder.load_file("RootWidget.kv")
        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        addMainScreen(self.screen_manager, self)
        self.screen_manager.current = "Main"
        self.current = "Main"
        self.processing = False
        self.manager_open = False
        self.filePath = ""
        self.symbol = []
        self.qty = []
        self.cost = []
        self.side = []
        Window.bind(on_keyboard=self.events)
        self.file_manager = MDFileManager(
            exit_manager=self.exit_manager,
            select_path=self.select_path,
        )
        self.file_manager.ext = ['.csv', '.CSV', '.xlsx', '.XLSX']
        self.popup = self.get_popup()
        self.no_data_popup = self.no_data_popup()
        end = time.time()
        print('elapsed time for startup is %d seconds ' % (end - start))

    def on_processing(self, instance, value):
        print('instance, value', instance, value)
```

I set the processing variable before and after code that does some heavy lifting as follows

```
  def gain_loss(self):
        self.processing = True
        try:
            gl = self.screen_manager.get_screen('GainLoss')
            gl.add_widgets()
        except ScreenManagerException:
            gl = GainLossScreen(self.screen_manager, name='GainLoss')
            self.screen_manager.add_widget(gl)
            gl.add_widgets()
        if len(tryout.product_dict) == 0:
            self.no_data_popup.open()
        else:
            self.screen_manager.current = 'GainLoss'
        self.processing = False
```

However, the spinner doesnt get activated. I debugged the MDSpinner source code and it does call the activation.start method when processing is set to True and stops the animation when processing is set to false. But the spinner just doesnt spin!.

Interestingly, if I comment out the last line self.processing = False, then the spinner starts spinning .

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are running the `gain_loss()` method on the main thread, then the `MDSpinner` will not be activated/deactivated until that method completes.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick! Much appreciated